# Text not being displayed in Grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uitableview

The text for each cell in a UITableView is not being displayed, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. I have 3 sections in the table view, and the sections are shown correctly, as is the number of rows for each section. However, the text inside each row for all the sections is empty. My code is:

[image: This is how its looking =[]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad    {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            listofsections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            NSArray *shuffle = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                           @"Display words in alphabetical order", @"Display words in shuffled order", nil];
            NSDictionary *shuffleDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:shuffle forKey:@"Object Key"];

            NSArray *wordFilter = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                @"Show all words", @"Show words not yet appeared", @"Show words marked correct", @"Show words marked incorrect", @"Show words marked as favorite", @"Show words saved for later", nil];
            NSDictionary *wordFilterDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:wordFilter forKey:@"Object Key"];

            NSArray *wordDisplay = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                @"Display words first", @"Display definition first", nil];
            NSDictionary *wordDisplayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:wordDisplay forKey:@"Object Key"];

            [listofsections addObject:shuffleDict];
            [listofsections addObject:wordFilterDict];
            [listofsections addObject:wordDisplayDict];

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
        }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

        return [listofsections count];
    }


    // Customize the number of rows in the table view.
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        //Number of rows it should expect should be based on the section
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [listofsections objectAtIndex:section];
        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Object Key"];
        return [array count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        //return UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }


    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


        if(section == 0) {
            return @"Word Display Order";
        }
        if (section == 1) {
            return @"Word Filter";
        }
        else 
            return @"Display Selection";


    }


    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }


        // Set up the cell...

        //First get the dictionary object
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [listofsections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Countries"];
        NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;


        return cell;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried printing NSLog(@"Value: %@", cellValue]; in the cell creation method to make sure your cellValue is not nil at that time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionaries you have created dont have the key @"Countries" wich you have used in 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: haha yup! Thank you so much for that. I copied it from another app I have written, and my proofreading skills have missed that line multiple times. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your init method for the cells with :

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

instead of the deprecated initWithFrame.

And also make sure that the string you're trying to set is not nil.

Comment: Ya I just realized that the string is nil. I am adding the string contents of each row into an array in my viewDidLoad. How do I get that array to print into my UITableView? Apparently, the way I did it in cellForRow is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Setting the text as cell.textLabel.text is the right way to go for default UITableViewCells. As long as you set something in there, it should appear in your cells.